# react-navigation import problems

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have installed and linked react-navigation into my project and somehow when I try importing it to my App.js code, it is showing me errors. I tried doing it many ways, none of which worked. I will be glad if you could help me resolve this issue.
This is the error I am getting in my Terminal window.
Thanks for your help.

[image]

This is my code
[image]

Comment: How are we supposed to detect the error without seeing your code? Please insert the code you have tried that raise the exception

Comment: How are you importing it?

Comment: error clearly says that `createNavigationContainer` is missing

Comment: @warl0ck how should I resolve it please?

Comment: @warl0ck I checked it and the file is not missing, so I do not see why it cannot be found

Comment: can you try reinstalling node modules and double check if react-navigation is actually installed or not

Comment: @warl0ck thanks, reinstalling node modules helped. Thank you very much!

Comment: cool, I have posted it as answer as well for others as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the error says its unable to find the files located in your `node_modules` chances are node modules are not correctly installed. Try re-installing node modules. It will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the cache.

`react-native start --reset-cache` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.

You can check the issue [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5222).

Comment: does not work for me, the error showing in the app says "Requiring unknown module 563. If you are sure the module is there, try restarting Metro Bundler. You may also want to run yarn or npm install (depending on your environment)."

Comment: you use expo or react-nativ-cli?